# Security Plugin from Grails?

Tags: security, plugins, grails

I try find some simple security plugin from `Grails`.

And first of all, i want ask you: what plugin you can recommend?

I not need super powerful plugin. Its must be simply and for small application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend [Spring Security](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core).  It is easy to configure, and very flexible. It can handle everything from simple login, to annotated access controls on methods, to various complicated login schemes.

It does have a fairly complicated API, but there is plenty of documentation, and you can be sure others are using it.

If you just want simple login, it is really easy to set up.

More info [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/).

Per @robbbert suggestion, here is an alternative -- the [Shiro](http://www.grails.org/plugin/shiro) plugin.  I cannot speak to its reliability/community/expandibility.

Comment: [+], although a brief discussion of the different plugins would be desirable.

Comment: @robbbert, its the only grails security plugin I have ever used...;) dont have knowledge to compare...did expand my answer a bit though

Comment: I recommend SpringSecurity, too.

Comment: This plugin is indeed simple. Try following examples on the net. http://grails.asia/grails-spring-security-core-plugin-example-annotations/

Answer (score 0):

We use [Apache Shiro](http://www.grails.org/plugin/shiro) which is very simple to use and set up. It works by convention and supports both authentication and authorization.